How can I force ParallelNeeds on Remote Kernels to load custom package from local machine?
I am running serial computation using 4 of 8 cores on my local Windows machine and 56 of 60 cores on a remote Linux machine:
If[$MachineName == "l9-0-kia2",
 $DefaultParallelKernels // Echo;
 $DefaultLocalKernel // Echo;
 $DefaultRemoteKernel // Echo;
 $DefaultParallelKernels = {4, "ssh://kia@vxenia?56"} // Echo;
 ]
$KernelCount // Echo;
LaunchKernels[];

My code loads my custom package XRS which an adapted and advanced version of well-known but outdated package of Ted Ersek:
Needs["Kia`XRS`"]
ParallelNeeds["Kia`XRS`"]

Until yesterday, I was quite sure that the ParallelNeeds command downloaded the package from a local directory. But yesterday I updated the package version in the local repository, and it turned out that the old version of the package was still downloaded to remote kernels:
ParallelEvaluate[XRootVersion]
 
(*
{"2.9a 24-05-02 10:25 (XRS.81)", "2.9a 24-05-02 10:25 (XRS.81)", \
"2.9a 24-05-02 10:25 (XRS.81)", "2.9a 24-05-02 10:25 (XRS.81)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 \
24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)", "2.9 24-02-22 15:15 (XRS.80)"}
*)

Obviously, it was downloaded from storage on a remote computer. Since I am a complete novice in Linux, I will not be able to update and upload a new version there without the help of my colleagues. Well, I wouldn’t want to bother them every time the package is updated. In this regard, I would like to make sure that the package is loaded onto the remote computer from the local storage. Is it possible to do this?
